# detect new browser window with WATIN

Tags: watin

is there a way to test wether a link was opened in a new browser-window (or browser-tab)?

**Update:**

So far I used the following code:

```
var newBrowserWindow = Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle(browserTitle));
Assert.That(newBrowserWindow.hWnd, Is.Not.EqualTo(existingBrowserWindow.hWnd));
```

Where I used the existingBrowserWindow to open a page and to click on a link. But when the link opens a new tab in the existing browser (default behaviour for IE with targer=_blank) it has the same window-handle, since it's the same browser window. So how can I detect a new tab?

Answer (score 4):

Some code of yours would help...,

Anyway, what I do when a link open a new browser window is

```
using (var newBrowser = WatiN.Core.Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle("Analytics - Read conversation"))
{
}
```

`Browser.AttachTo` supports `Find.ByUri()`, `Find.ByTitle()` and `Find.By("hwnd", windowHandle)` according to documentation. I only tested `Find.ByUri()` and `Find.ByTitle()` methods.

if you want to detect if you action has opened a new window you could do

```
public bool TryGetNewBrowser(out IE browser, string title)
{
    try
    {
        browser = WatiN.Core.Browser.AttachTo<IE>(Find.ByTitle(title));
        return true;
    }
    catch(WatiN.Core.Exceptions.BrowserNotFoundException)
    {
        browser = null;
        return false;
    }
}
```

As far as I know, there is no support in WatiN for new tab. But the default behavior of internet explorer is to open new links in new window.

Comment: Hi, I edited my post to include some code. Well, actually I want to make sure that a link is being opend in a new window instead of the same window. So just looking for an existing browser is not enough, I also have to make sure, that it's different from the browser-window where I clicked the link.

Comment: @nyn3x, thanks for your additional details. To the question "So how can I detect a new tab?", I answered: "there is no support in WatiN for new tab". but you say "default behaviour for IE with target=_blank" and I think you are wrong (just tried with IE7 and IE8).

Comment: @Baptiste-Pernet shut - on my dev-machine i have IE) - might this be just because of that? But Chrome also opens target=_blank in a new tab not a new window. Darn - I missed you're comment on WatiN not supporting new tabs ... that would come in handy now; especially since most browsers are by now more driven by tabs instead of windows.

Comment: Will this kind of approach will work with Firefox also?

Comment: last time I check (2011), the watin extension for firefox was only a some sort of javascript interpreter. I don't think it will work. But you should definitely give it a try.