# Switching tabs in IE while doing automation

Tags: c#, watin

I am trying to automate a web page. On it there is a link and by clicking it it opens in another tab. I am stuck here. I have tried the `Redirect` option but it didn't work.

This is the web page code on which I am trying to automate:

```
<td class="">
    <a href="../TMI/viewCustomerDetails.jsp?mcid=30000248243" target="_new">30000248243</a>
</td>
```

and this is what I am doing:

```
public void ThenIClickAtTheMCID()
{
     var MCID = WebBrowser.Current.Link(Find.ByText("30000248243"));
     if (!MCID.Exists)
     {
          Assert.Fail("Unable to find the MCID Name");
          MCID.Click();
     }
}
```

It does open the link but not able to move to the next tab. How can I proceed further?

This is my `WebBrowser` class:

```
using TechTalk.SpecFlow ;

using WatiN.Core;

namespace WebTest
{
    class WebBrowser
    {
        public static IE Current
        {
            get
            {
                if (!ScenarioContext.Current.ContainsKey("browser")) ScenarioContext.Current["browser"] = new IE();
                return ScenarioContext.Current["browser"] as IE;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what technology are you using for automating the browser? Selenium? you should tag your question with that and remove the `Specflow`, `Cucumber` and `asp.net` tags as this question is not related to them. You are really asking 'how can I open a link in a new tab using selenium', and this has a [few answers already](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=how+can+I+open+a+link+in+a+new+tab+using+selenium&oq=how+can+I+open+a+link+in+a+new+tab+using+selenium&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: i am not using selenium i am doing this in visual studio using [tag:specflow] for [tag:Cucumber] that is [tag:BDD]

Comment: What technology is the line `WebBrowser.Current.Link(Find.ByText)` and `MCID.Click()` using? This is not specflow, cucumber or bdd this is some web browser automation technology like selenium, and this is where your problem is. This is not related to specflow at all.

Comment: You need to tag your question with the appropriate technology in order to get people who can actually answer your question to see it. Tagging it with specflow isn't going to help you here as no one who knows specflow and cucumber will be able to help with this as it's NOT specflow or cucumber related. Just because you are using a technology doesn't mean you should tag it with that technology. Otherwise why not tag it `windows` and `visual studio` ?

Comment: `Web Browser` is a class that i have created

Answer (score 0):

[This might help](https://rawwool.wordpress.com/article/watin-how-to-simulate-tabbing-34wimsoj039eh-3/),

basically you can try:

```
WebBrowser.Current.PressTab();
WebBrowser.Current.WaitForComplete();
```

Comment: not working.
`WebBrowser.Current.PressTab();`  is obselete

Comment: also your tone is coming across as disrespectful. I have tried to point out your issue, and suggested what you are actually trying to ask. Once you knew that I would have thought you could find the answer with some simple googling. I even did that and posted what I thought might be an answer. You should really learn how best to help yourself, and be a little bit more friendly to those that are going out of their way to help you.

Comment: i am not trying to disrepectful, apologize if felt so. googilng doesn't work :)
actually i was trying to switch browser windows.

Comment: So your question was not about what you are trying to do? simply googling 'switch browser windows watin' gives  3 questions with similar issues. [This one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750113/detect-new-browser-window-with-watin) seems the most likely to give a solution. It's very frustrating to have wasted time trying to help you when you are not even able to ask the correct question, or answer my question about which web automation technology you are using, or perform a simple google to try and find an answer. please try and do a little research first.

Answer (score 0):

As a reference if you have another tab opened by any action it is much better to find the existing instance of IE and attach to it and continue as if you started it. Like this:

`var newTabOpened = Browser.AttachTo(typeof(IE)), Find.ByUrl("http://www.google.com")`

from here you can keep working with newTabOpened as any other `IE` instace within WatIn.